# Управленка для скрипта парсера на Python

Tags: python, grab

Я пишу скрипт парсера, используя библиотеку **Grab**, к примеру, записываю результаты в БД или же в CSV. Часто вижу в Сети запросы о реализации **"управленки" для парсера**, например, в виде **Html странички**. И вот вопрос заключается в том, как можно это реализовать связь **Python скрипта и html странички**, в какую сторону копать, какие ключевые слова гуглить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй flask для морды, самый простой вариант за 10 мин. можно накидать. Можешь связку с jquery для красоты использовать.